# Django Docker Nginx can't load static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a django project. I want to deploy it on AWS using Docker. Here is my `services` in `docker-compose-prod.yml`:

```
...
  api:
    image: meduzzen-backend-api
    container_name: django
    entrypoint: ./start_prod.sh
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./code:/apps
      - static:/code/static
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - api-db-redis
...
  nginx:
    image: meduzzen-backend-nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - ./nginx-conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api

volumes:
  static:
...
```

`meduzzen-backend-api` image was built from Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.3-alpine

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
# Enable pytest-django 
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=meduzzen_backend.settings

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade pip

COPY . .

# Copy start.sh script into project folder
COPY start.sh .

# Give access rights to start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
RUN chmod +x start_prod.sh

EXPOSE 8000
```

`meduzzen-backend-nginx` was built from Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`default.conf`:

```
upstream django {
    server api:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

`start_prod.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
gunicorn meduzzen_backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Pages are loaded but it can't load static files. In ngnix container I can see `static` folder with all of the content. In settings.py DEBUG = False. What causes this problem?

## What have I tried

I tried to go to `http://localhost:8000/static/admin/img/calendar-icons.svg/` path but I can't see the svg file. I also tried to rename STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting the `/static` directory in your application with a named volume.  That will hide the contents of the image (it is not a reliable path to share files from one container to another) and could cause this problem.  Can you copy the static assets into your Nginx proxy image, and delete all of the `volumes:` mounts?

Comment: @DavidMaze I've deleted static volume and copied static in the ngnix container but the error is still appearing.

Comment: `:8000` is Django's port. Remove port from the url and try again, post error text fron nginx error.log